# Is there a way to reject a push request to a git repo on the central server if the submitted code does not conform to coding standards?

Tags: git

So, I am looking for a way for git to reject the changes that a developer may be trying to push to the git repository on the central server, if the code he has submitted (I'm concerned with C# and Typescript codebases) does not conform to the coding standards established for the team. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is there an objective test, like a script which inspects the code and, if the code fails the standard, returns a failure code? Then you certainly can use [server-side git hooks]. But that may cover only the uninteresting things like tabs vs. spaces.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Well, tab vs spaces, while not the sole criterion, is important in this case, coz my team messes that up often, and our manager is really tired of all these non-standardized, difficult to read code. But to answer your question as to whether there's an objective test, I'm just looking to enforce the recommended C# and Typescript coding conventions. "StyleCop Analyzer" ruleset, as such, should do the trick. How do I integrate it with git?

Comment: Ah, I failed to add the link when I wrote the comment. I think I looked at this one: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy explaining how to run a check and reject a commit in case of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce Pull Requests!! . Before your code gets to be merged on the server , it has to go through code review and discussion among some engineers who feel that its as per the standards . Once approved , now this PR can be merged to target branch.
Also you should lock your master/ so that no Push will be allowed and engineers don't force push their changes without reviewing.

Comment: That would be a manual process, I'm looking for some sort of automation.

Comment: I see, you want to have a checkstyle feature like eslint that would automatically format your code.
You can also try [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)

Comment: Looks like SonarQube may be the thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Do you know more about it? Have you used it ever? I had a few questions, and if there's a way I can reach out to you directly through a text, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities.
Git itself propose [Integration-Manager Workflow](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) where every developer has own public repo, when code is ready put things to own repo and send message to integration manager to merge his code. If integration manager says that code is good enough merge code from developer public repo to his "blessed repo", where only him can push. Rest of developers should merge changes to theirs code. Other variation of this method is to use different branches for every developer, and only integration manager merge it to master, but this method is without authorization.
Other possibility is to use some git server offers control of [pull requests](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull), when code is ready for publish, developer send pull request, and after code review someone with credentials can accept this request.